# Regex in Python - Substring with single "re.sub" call

Tags: python, regex, substring

I am looking into the Regex function in Python. 
As part of this, I am trying to extract a substring from a string.

For instance, assume I have the string:

```
<place of birth="Stockholm">
```

Is there a way to extract Stockholm with a **single** regex call?

So far, I have:

```
location_info = "<place of birth="Stockholm">"

#Remove before
location_name1 = re.sub(r"<place of birth=\"", r"", location_info)
#location_name1 --> Stockholm">

#Remove after
location_name2 = re.sub(r"\">", r"", location_name1)
#location_name2 --> Stockholm
```

Any advice on how to extract the string Stockholm, without using two "re.sub" calls is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are removing the rest of the string, instead of selecting the part you want with something like <.*="(.*)".*>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can match the beginning up to the double quotes, and match and capture all the characters other than double quotes after that:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'<place of birth="([^"]*)')
location_info = "<place of birth=\"Stockholm\">"
match = p.search(location_info)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/fIYLY0)

The `<place of birth="` is matched as a literal, and `([^"]*)` is a capture group 1 matching 0 or more characters other than `"`. The value is accessed with `.group(1)`.

Here is a [**REGEX demo**](https://regex101.com/r/pP4fD6/2).

Comment: I just compared my regex and vks' and found out that mine is a bit quicker :) Also, of your string may contain more than just `"place of birth="..."` my regex will deal with that task better.

Answer (score 1):

```
print re.sub(r'^[^"]*"|"[^"]*$',"",location_info)
```

This should do it for you.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vV1wW6/30#python

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason why you are removing the rest of the string, instead of selecting the part you want with something like

```
location_info = "<place of birth="Stockholm">"
location_info = re.search('<.*="(.*)".*>', location_info, re.IGNORECASE).group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

this code tested under python 3.6

```
 test =  '<place of birth="Stockholm">'
 resp = re.sub(r'.*="(\w+)">',r'\1',test)
 print (resp)


 Stockholm
```